# Memory Leak Error Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

```
InputSream backgroundBitmap;
//backgroundBitmap is initialized from asset image.png
immutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(backgroundBitmap);
```

getting this error:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)

Help me to solve this.

Comment: seems like your image is too large to handle

Comment: a search for this error reveals hundreds of tips to deal with it...

Comment: Its just 350-500 Kb. And 612 X 612 Pixels.

Comment: It's just 500k 612x612 in a file.  How many bytes is that when you load it into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.. file from asset

```
File f = new File("file:///android_assetassets/mydemo.png")

public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale*=2;

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

this function will scale bitmap as you pass width and height

Comment: add `catch(Error e){}` because that is what should be handled on low-end devices

Comment: catch (OutOfMemoryError err) {
    // TODO: handle exception
   }

Comment: by this way you can catchh... but by provided function your OutOfMemory error problem will solve....

Comment: I have InputStream from asset. How can i make File Object from InputStream ?

Comment: nope, error can occur anyway, function is working with `REQUIRED_WIDTH` and `REQUIRED_HEIGHT`, if used incorrectly, it won't solve a thing

Comment: Ok.. So what will solve my problem Sir ?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(your fileInputStrema,null,o); so you not have to pass file object..

Comment: This function is not working in 2.2 i guess.. Sanket Kachhela...

Comment: and 

InputSream backgroundBitmap;
//backgroundBitmap is initialized from asset image.png
immutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(backgroundBitmap);

this is what i did but it is giving me memory leak error !

Comment: I am not able to pass these two parameters null,0. it is giving me error that method not found.